# White background transforms into an other color after image creation

Tags: compression, gd, image-uploading

So the user uploads an image (jpeg, gif or png);
And I should convert it to PNG, so I'm doing something like:

```
if ($typeImgFunction == 'jpeg') $imgCreate      = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileName);
else if ($typeImgFunction == 'gif') $imgCreate  = imagecreatefromgif($fileName);
else if ($typeImgFunction == 'png') $imgCreate  = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);
...
...
$displayImg = imagepng($dstFinal, $src);
```

The problem is that the white color (#fffff) in the uploaded image become a liter white (#FEFEFE) and it's ugly..

I tried to play with the quality parameter of imagepng putting something like:

```
$displayImg = imagepng($dstFinal, $src, 0); // 0 for no compression at all
```

But really it did not change anything...

Would you guys happend to have an idea ?

Comment: Is this the case for all file extensions? Of only jpeg or something?

Comment: I have the same thing for PNG, GPEG and GIF

Comment: Any luck with this issue??